# How to setup permissions for AWS ACM to limit user per domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-certificate-manager

I'm trying to set up the deploy user for a development environment.

Is there any way to limit this user to request a certificate (**acm:RequestCertificate**) only for a specific set of domains. For example **"*.dev.mydomain.com"**

Something like this?:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "acm:RequestCertificate",
    "acm:AddTagsToCertificate",
    "acm:DescribeCertificate"
  ],
  "Condition": {"aws:DomainName": "*.dev.mydomain.com" }
  "Resource": [
    "*"
  ]
}
```

My goal is to have the user, that can do any type of operations, but only to specific tag or domain in this case.

It seems to be the dead end in AWS permission mechanism.

I want user to be able to create/delete/update certs/Route53/nodes, but only for let say development environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few conditions that you can use for [ACM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awscertificatemanager.html#awscertificatemanager-aws_RequestTag___TagKey_).

The `RequestCertificate` only supports the following conditions:

- `aws:RequestTag/${TagKey}`
- `aws:TagKeys`

Perhaps instead you could require the domain be tagged with a particular value (such as the domain being whitelisted).

Then create a [custom config rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config_develop-rules.html) which checks the tag matches the domain. If this fails have the remediation be a Lambda function to remove the certificate.

Comment: This is kind of dead end in AWS permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately you're limited to what AWS provides, over time more conditions are being added but at this time you're limited to what is provided. This is where most people add automation to remove resources (which isn't ideal) if they don't match the required rulesets.

Answer (score -2):

In your case it looks like you are trying to grant an IAM policy to developers to allow them to make subdomains and certificates for them without interfering with production.

In this case I would recommend looking at AWS Organisations and delegating the whole dev.example.com to a new AWS account with a whole new account number. Then any permissions given to developers with IAM policies in the new account will not be able to break your production environment.